Oracle Apex 22.1 Interactive Grid Column Should be added in Uppercase only
I have an editable interactive grid with column DEPT.
SELECT, DEPT, ENAME, ORG FROM EMP;

The values in DEPT should be in Uppercase only and with no spaces allowed.
How can this be achieved.

A simple option is to create validations; choose "Function body (returning error text)".
No spaces:
if instr(:DEPT, ' ') > 0 then
   return 'Must not contain spaces';
end if;

Uppercase:
if :DEPT <> upper(:DEPT) then
   return 'Must be in upper case';
end if;


There are various other options; for example,

you could put everything into a single validation,
use different functions (e.g. regular expressions)
enforce those rules in the database (create a trigger which puts DEPT value into uppercase and removes spaces)

but code I posted is really simple and obvious, easy to read and maintain.

What about handling it on Client/Browser side by a dynamic action with
Event: Change
Selection Type: Column(s)
Interactive Grid: Your IG
Column(s): DEPT

and with a set value action:
Type: Javascript 
Javascript Expression: $v('DEPT').toUpperCase().replace(/\s/g, "");
Affected Elements: Columns -> DEPT

and don't forget to enable Suppress Change event.
This way, whenever the column DEPT is changed, the dynamic action will be triggered and change the value of column by the Javascript code.
